# Inserting only 2 of the same radomized values into array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, random

Im working on a card matching game in c++ I need to have 6 cards on a board 3  different pairs of cards. I have a loop that adds only one unique card into the array. How can I make this do 2 cards?

```
void initializeGameData(char cards[])
{
    char card1 = 'A', card2 = 'K', card3 = 'Q';

    char tempCards[ARR_MAX/2];
    tempCards[0] = card1;
    tempCards[1] = card2;
    tempCards[2] = card3;
    //AKQ

    int maxNum = 2, minNum = 0;
    int value = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_MAX; i++)
    {
        while (1) {
            value = (rand() % (maxNum + 1 - minNum) + minNum);
            bool alreadyPresent = false;

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { //You only have to check against already inserted values!
                                  //Before you were checking against uninitialized values!!
                if (tempCards[value] == cards[j]){
                    alreadyPresent = true;
                    break; //I don't need to further iterate the array
                }
            }
            if (alreadyPresent)
                continue;
            else
                break; //I can proceed with the next value, user has not to reenter the value
        }
        cards[i] = tempCards[value];
    }
}
```

Edit:
After posting this question I realized if nothing else is possible I could just as a second duplicate value into the `tempCards` array and tweak that to work

Comment: There's probably a typo in the code. Please check your for loop again

Comment: Sorry my bad, fixed it

Comment: Using random to select a card and then having to search to determine if you already selected that card is an anti-pattern.  There are better ways, such as random-shuffling all valid indices and choosing two, or using something like a set and removing cards from that set as you choose them.